# Examine if is Euler circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, eulerian-path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w96d.jpg)

As you can see the vertices are $u_o,u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5$.As a result are 6 that means are even number.
With the theory
"a graph will contain an Euler  circuit if all  vertices have even degree. "
So this is Euler circle right?

Comment: Looks to me like $u_2$ and $u_3$ have  degree $3$, which is odd.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Hi Robert. Because it has u2 and u3 degree 3 it means it is not Euler?

Comment: A graph with some vertices of odd degree can't have an Eulerian circuit.  If there are two vertices of odd degree, there is an Eulerian **path** that starts at one of these vertices and ends at the other.